# If condition not working in Javascript/Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-mobile

```
b.addEventListener('touchend', function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    end_x_position = (event.changedTouches[0].pageX + 'px');
    end_y_position = event.changedTouches[0].pageY + 'px';

    if ((posX < end_x_position) && (end_x_position < totalWidth)) //THIS PART DOESNOT RUN EVEN IF CONDITION IS TRUE
    {
        console.log("iff");
        alert("iff");
        b.style.left = intial_x_position;
        b.style.top = intial_y_position;
    } else {
        console.log("else");

        b.style.left = end_x_position - xbox;
        b.style.top = end_y_position - ybox;
    }

}, false);
```

Comment: Try `parseInt(end_x_position)`

Comment: variable "end_x_position" is string and  you are comparing it with variable "posX & totalWidth" I think these variables are float.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if((posX<end_x_position)&&(end_x_position<totalWidth)) //THIS PART DOESNOT RUN EVEN IF CONDITION IS TRUE
```

For example, this is like trying this:

```
3 < "hello world"
```

Check some of your first lines:

```
end_x_position=(event.changedTouches[0].pageX + 'px');
end_y_position=event.changedTouches[0].pageY + 'px';
```

The whole `end_x_position` will hold something like `400px`. This is a string and you can't compare `String` with `Number`.

Instead of that, you should do this:

```
end_x_position= parseInt(event.changedTouches[0].pageX);
end_y_position= parseInt(event.changedTouches[0].pageY);
```

And your `if` statement will work as expected as you'll be comparing `Number` with `Number`.

Answer (score 0):

you stringed it with this line:

```
end_x_position=(event.changedTouches[0].pageX + 'px');
end_y_position=event.changedTouches[0].pageY + 'px';
```

leave off the px or do this:

```
if((posX< parseInt(end_x_position))&&( parseInt(end_x_position) <totalWidth))
```

Comment: will really `end_x_position` be parsed into a `Number` in your case?